# My Image Won't Add C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
public ActionResult GeneratePdf(int id)
{
    var labelRepository = new LabelRepository();
    var label = labelRepository.GetLabel(id);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(label.PDFLocation))
    {
        var action = Url.Content("~/Label/ViewPdf/" + id); //doc 

        Doc theDoc = new Doc();
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/" + filename + ".pdf");

        theDoc.AddImageUrl("action");
        theDoc.Save(path);
        theDoc.Clear();

        label.PDFLocation = path;
        labelRepository.Save();

        return base.File(path, "application/pdf");
    }
    else
    {
        return base.File(label.PDFLocation, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

This won't add my image url so my pdf won't open up so I can see it. Any ideas?-

Comment: What library are you using to generate the PDF?

Comment: What do you mean it won't add the image URL?

Comment: @msarchet It gives me an error at the theDoc.AddImageUrl("action") saying unable to add image

Comment: "action" doesn't look like a valid URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example [here](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf5net/source/5-abcpdf5/doc/1-methods/addimageurl.htm), a complete URL is being passed to the `AddImageUrl()` function, not a fragment of an URL, as your example shows.

Perhaps you need a call to [`RouteUrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl.aspx) so that you can get a complete Url to pass to your `AddImageUrl()` method?

Comment: I'll take a look into this RouteLink()

Comment: @Samjus: It looks like `RouteLink` returns an anchor tag, not an Url.  Let me see if I can find something better.

Comment: @Samjus: There it is, `RouteUrl`.  Edited my answer.